# Any way to run C# through the Terminal?

Tags: c#, unix, mono, terminal

I'm looking for something like JS/Ruby engines that enable you to run commands from terminal. Something like to what LINQPad do but much more simple.

I know C# is not design to be used a a script but would be helpful to have, for example, a mono console application with `Main()` awaiting for commands came from terminal.

May can I implement such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [interactive C# shell](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Sep-08.html)?

There is also a GUI version called gsharp

More [here](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl)

Comment: Awesome! I already got this on my terminal thanks to Xamarin stuff I've installed before. Exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

You can try Jon Skeet's [Snippy](http://csharpindepth.com/Downloads.aspx). Source code is also available so you can tweak it or just use as a sample to create your own.

Also, Visual Studio has build in solution - "Debug->Windows->Immediate". Just create empty console project and start typing commands in the Immediate window.

Comment: Well it was made by Jon probably will work fine! I'll give it a try...   I already knew about immediate, but I was looking for something quick and easy to try out any commands that come in mind eventually.